# How to pass "double" via write() call when it accepts only const void * type argument?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pointers

Given `double temp = 6.5;` how could I pass it to the UNIX [write()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/write.htm) system call:

`write(fd[1], (WTF?), 100)`

1. `fd[1]` is a file descriptor.
2. `100` is a fixed buffer size to handle large number values, just in case.

What do I put it in the middle? I've tried **itoa**, **&temp**, ***temp**, **(char) temp**, and a few other ways by googling my way to different solutions, but with no luck so far. Honestly I don't even know what type is **const void ***. I just know it will stop complaining if I pass a string directly such as "Hello World" to the 2nd argument.

Comment: Do you want to `write` a decimal representation of the `double` or its bytes? In the latter case, `write(fd[1], &temp, sizeof temp);`, in the former, `sprintf` it to a `char str[100]` and `write(fd[1], str, strlen(str));`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I want a child process send me the value of temp, so I can do some computation in the parent process. I know how to go from char array to a double, but not the other way around. If I could send double directly via write, great, otherwise char array will work too because I could just convert it back to decimal in the main process.

Comment: Then use `write(fd[1], &temp, sizeof temp);` that sends fewer bytes and has no risk of losing precision.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, much appreciated. The sprintf method works at least. I'll try &temp method now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `write` is a pointer to some location in memory, and the third parameter is the number of bytes from that location in memory that you want to write to the file.  So your code would be:

```
double temp = 6.5;
write(fd[1], &temp, sizeof(temp));
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, though.  To be clear, this will write the binary representation of your `double` to the file.  On most platforms, that will be the following series of bytes (represented here in hexadecimal):

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 26 64
```

If this is supposed to be a text file, then you'll want to convert your number to a string first.

```
double temp = 6.5;
char buffer[20];
sprintf(buffer, "%g", temp);
write(fd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

This would write "6.5" to your file.

Comment: P Daddy, I am using pipe() to communicate between parent and child processes. Once I write &temp through the pipe, you are saying I will receive a binary representation of 6.5, right (e.g. 0xffffff83 in my case)? How could I convert it back to decimal? I have declared a buffer array of size 100, and I am using read() function to accept incoming transfer from write().

Comment: @TwilightPonyInc. You don't need any conversion if you send the bytes, just `double receive; read(fd[0], &receive, sizeof receive);` on the other end of the pipe (assuming that's `fd[0]` there), and hey presto, you have the value as a `double`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. Wow I feel really stupid right now by how simple it is. I think I've tried about 6 different ways, but not what you have suggested above. That's it, starting next week I'm going to dedicate myself to reading `Head First C`.

Comment: I suggest using `snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%g", temp);`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind writing binary data to the file try

`write(fd[1], &temp, sizeof(temp));`

If you actually want to write the value to a text file then you will need to convert it to a string first. If that's the case you can try something along the lines of:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 100

double temp = 17.5;
char* str[BUFF_SIZE];

sprintf(str, "%lf", temp);

write(fd[1], str, strlen(str));
```

Comment: On a related note, how would I dereference that from the read() function? I have created a char buffer[100] array, which I pass into read(fd[0], buffer, 100).

Comment: Don't `read()` into a `char` buffer; read into another `double` same as writing: `double temp; read(fd[0], &temp, sizeof temp);`

Comment: For the first method which writes the binary double you can use:
`read(fd[1], &temp, sizeof(temp));`

For the second method that stores the string it will be more complex since we are not using a predefined size.
    `char* buffer[BUFF_SIZE], c;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        read(fd[1], &c, sizeof(c));
        buffer[i] = c;
        ++i;
    } while (c != '\0');`